# How to use Mockito in real Web container to simulate some interfaces

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, wildfly

Is it possible to use Mockito to mock interfaces not in unit tests nor Arquilian tests, but in a real WEB container? 
What I want to do is to simulate these two interfaces from IBM Filenet API: [Document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/core/Document.html) and [Properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/property/Properties.html) to test Spring application running in the container (WildFly) without a real connection to IBM/Filenet framework.

---

The UnitTest works fine, for example this one:

```
@Test
public void mock() {
    Document d = Mockito.mock(Document.class);
    Properties p = Mockito.mock(Properties.class);

    Mockito.when(d.getProperties()).thenReturn(p);
    Mockito.when(p.getStringValue("Ala")).thenReturn("Bella");
    ....
    ....
 }
```

but when I am trying to run this code deployed to the container:

```
@Override
public DocumentSet someMethod(String ..... ) {

    Document d = mock(Document.class);  // this line throws an Exception
    Properties p = mock(Properties.class);
    when(d.getProperties()).thenReturn(p);
    .....
```

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` exception at this line: `Document d = mock(Document.class);`

```
1:18:11,310 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1) Encountered an error executing step csvFilesProcessStep in job process_csv_files: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/Mockito
    at com.somepackage.step.ce.CeOperationsProcessorTestImpl.searchAndFetchDocumentsById(CeOperationsProcessorTestImpl.java:44)
    at com.somepackage.step.CvsFilesProcessor.processFile(CvsFilesProcessor.java:110)
    at com.somepackage.step.CvsFilesProcessor.process(CvsFilesProcessor.java:83)
    at com.somepackage.step.CvsFilesProcessor.process(CvsFilesProcessor.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.Mockito from [Module "deployment.someapp_web-1.1.3-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 39 more
```

For now I implemented my own test implementation of these two interfaces, but it was tedious because they have several hundred methods.

Comment: Looks like  you  have missed mockito jar in your application.  HOw are you building and deploying? (if maven / gradle -  mockito will usually have test scope and not go into deployable artifact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you have Mockito as a test dependency in Maven (or whatever you use to build your code). In the `pom.xml` file, there would be a line `<scope>test</scope>` in the `<dependency>` tag where Mockito is imported. If you comment that line out, you should be able to find that class. Also, WildFly needs the Mockito JAR file, so make sure it is either in your WAR file or in a lib directory.

However... aren't you trying to do an integration test on a production server? I can't for the life of me imagine why you would want to do such a thing. It's a bit of work, but what you want to do is write an integration test that starts your server, deploys your code, tests it, and shuts down the server. Do a Google for `java integration test`.

Comment: Thank you, I found the reason - I simply commented out `<scope>test</scope>` in `pom.xml`, but maven still inherited `test` scope from the parent project. When I declared explicitely `<scope>compile</scope>` everything works now.